# pandas dataframe output need to be a string instead of a list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a requirement that the result value should be a string. But when I calculate the maximum value of dataframe it gives the result as a list.

```
import pandas as pd

def answer_one():
    df_copy = [df['# Summer'].idxmax()]
    return (df_copy)

df = pd.read_csv('olympics.csv', index_col=0, skiprows=1)
for col in df.columns:
    if col[:2]=='01':
        df.rename(columns={col:'Gold'+col[4:]}, inplace=True)
    if col[:2]=='02':
        df.rename(columns={col:'Silver'+col[4:]}, inplace=True)
    if col[:2]=='03':
        df.rename(columns={col:'Bronze'+col[4:]}, inplace=True)
    if col[:1]=='№':
        df.rename(columns={col:'#'+col[1:]}, inplace=True)

names_ids = df.index.str.split('\s\(') 
df.index = names_ids.str[0] # the [0] element is the country name (new index) 
df['ID'] = names_ids.str[1].str[:3] # the [1] element is the abbreviation or ID (take first 3 characters from that)

df = df.drop('Totals')
df.head()

answer_one()
```

But here the answer_one() will give me a List as an output and not a string. Can someone help me know how this came be converted to a string or how can I get the answer directly from dataframe as a string. I don't want to convert the list to a string using str(df_copy).

Comment: Well, for starters, you are *wrapping it in a list*: `df_copy = [df['# Summer'].idxmax()]`

Answer (score 0):

Your first solution would be as @juanpa.arrivillaga put it: To not wrap it. Your function becomes:

```
def answer_one():
    df_copy = df['# Summer'].idxmax()
    return (df_copy)

>>> 1
```

Another thing that you might not be expecting but `idxmax()` will return the index of the max, perhaps you want to do:

```
def answer_one():
    df_copy = df['# Summer'].max()
    return (df_copy)

>>> 30
```

Since you don't want to do `str(df_copy)` you can do `df_copy.astype(str)` instead.

Here is how I would write your function:

```
def get_max_as_string(data, column_name):
    """ Return Max Value from a column as a string."""
    return data[column_name].max().astype(str)


get_max_as_string(df, '# Summer')
>>> '30'
```